# Generating smaller video file size from frames

Tags: matlab, video, video-encoding, steganography

I am doing a project in which I have a video I divide the video into frames and then the image steganography is applied to the frames and the encoded frames are generated. Then the encoded frames are to be converted into video again. All of the methods are applied successfully but the only problem is that I get the encoded video which is very large then the original video. I am using the `movie2avi` function to generate the video.

Can someone suggest any way to generate the video which is not very large compared to the original video?

Comment: Steganographic content will likely get obliterated by any lossy compression scheme.  Is that what you really want to be doing?

Comment: @John: The OP didn't indicate which codec is being used. `movie2avi` includes a `'None'` codec option. And it depends on what the steganographic content is -I imagine that there are techniques that work with compressed video without manipulating the codec itself.

Comment: @horchler Since OP was concerned about video size, I assumed he was not using 'None' but your point is a most excellent one.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're using [`movie2avi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie2avi.html), you have a limited choice of very poor codecs (compression formats). If you have a new enough version of Matlab (R2009b+ I think) you should be using the [`VideoWriter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html) class instead. The choice of codecs is still not very good, but they are of much better quality. You didn't indicate which codec (or OS) you're using so I can't recommend an alternative.

Second, even under ideal circumstances you should expect your movie file to get larger with what you're doing unless you apply additional compression. Adding steganographic content is akin to adding noise so you're making the data harder to compress. In both `movie2avi` and `VideoWriter` you can adjust the compression level or quality depending on the codec. Also, the default `movie2avi` codec under Linux and OS X uses no compression so the file will be huge if you haven't changed that.

If `VideoWriter` doesn't meet your needs (or if your version doesn't have it) you can try my [`QTWriter`](https://github.com/horchler/QTWriter) class on GitHub that allows one to export QuickTime movies in Matlab. It works very much like `VideoWriter`, but allows you to create high quality QuickTime movies using a few image-based codecs. No inter-frame compression is used and the PNG and TIFF formats are lossless (this may be important to your steganographic application) while being very efficient at encoding content like that often generated in Matlab. There is also a JPEG format that may be better suited to general images. The QuickTime files can then be converted to other formats if needed. You can [read more and see examples here](http://horchler.github.io/QTWriter/) and download the [single M-file here](https://github.com/horchler/QTWriter/raw/master/QTWriter.zip).

Comment: i HAVE USE THIS AND IT GENERATE THE FILE BUT ANOTHER PROBLEM IS ARISE THAT AT RECEVER SIZE I HV ONLY THE ENCODED VIDEO AND THEIR I HAVE TO PERFORM DECODING AND FOR THIS PURPOSE I FIRST I HAVE TO DIVIDE VIDEO INTO FRAMES BUT ITS MOV FILE IT CAN'T B DIVIDED INTO FRAMES THEN HOW TO GET FRAMES FROM MOV FILE

Comment: PLEASE DON'T YELL with capital letters. You used "this" - which "this"? `VideoWriter` or my `QTWriter`? What were you doing before when you used `movie2avi` to create a file? Have you looked at `VideoReader`? Maybe this is a different question from the one you asked here?

Answer (score 1):

This is completely dependent on what you are trying to hide in the original video. Remember that the original video is using a compression codec that can take advantage of minimal change frame to frame and various other things, but if you go and try to hide something in that video through steganography, you are making it more difficult for the compression algorithm to do that, which will definitely result in a larger file. So you have to be careful what you are attempting to do, and how you are attempting to encode it.